# h:panel group not rendering properly

Tags: jsf, seam

I have a panel popup. It should be hidden on page load and on click of a link, it should be displayed.I have written the following code.

```
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{showTerritoryDropdown}">
    <div class="form-row float">
        <label for="territory">Territory:</label>
        <h:selectOneMenu style="width: 200px" id="territoryDropdownId" styleClass="searchCategory" >
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="ALL" itemValue="0" />
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Worldwide" itemValue="1" />
            <f:selectItems value="#{reasearchSPTDetailsService.getTerritoryList()}" />
        </h:selectOneMenu>
    </div>
</h:panelGroup>
```

I have declared showTerritoryDropdown as

```
@Out(required = false)
boolean showTerritoryDropdown = false;
```

On click of a link, I am setting `showTerritoryDropdown = true;` Bt even then panel popup is not displayed. I think it is a m inute mistake but I am not getting as I am new to coding. Pls help me out.

Comment: Show your Managed Bean code.

Comment: This is a piece of code where I am setting the dropdown to true.public String fetchLeftNavInfoPageForMovie(Integer progId, Integer typeId,
   String type) {
  System.out.println(showTerritoryDropdown);
  // International will not have Documents
  bmSelectedType = type;
  bmSelectedTypeId = typeId;
  showTerritoryDropdown = true;
  System.out.println(showTerritoryDropdown);

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Most symptoms indicate that you try to ajax-render a component *not physically present in the view*. Thus you get the error, as JSF can't know what to update: as ajax call finishes, components with specified ids will have them replaced with new components derived from the server.

So, this won't work:

```
<h:panelGroup id="id" rendered="#{bean.rendered}" />
<h:commandButton>
    <f:ajax render="id" />
</h:commandButton>
```

While this will work as expected:

```
<h:panelGroup id="id">
    <h:panelGroup rendered="#{bean.rendered}" />
</h:panelGroup>
<h:commandButton>
    <f:ajax render="id" />
</h:commandButton>
```

So, the solution is to place your to-be-updated component within a component that's always present in the view.